# small span div with bootstrap 2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm using bootstrap 2 and I need to have 3 span, but the one in the middle should be really small to handle an image to show/hide the span on the left. 
The problem is that I can't put all three span on the same line. Looks like the span with the image is taking the all place and not just 10px

Here is my code:

```
<style>
.myspan {
    width:10px;        
}
```

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3" style="background-color: red">this is fluid</div>
        <div class="myspan"><img src="~/Images/bullet.png" /></div>
        <div class="span9" style="background-color: blue">yeah!</div>        
    </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use span3, span1 and span8 to occupy the 12 column grid and line them up. Use a custom class to specify a width and remove the margin. But use the custom CSS in a higher priority order i.e. new file, loading it after all the CSS so that you need not use `!important`. Try to avoid inline styles as well.

```js
$('.span1').on('click', function() {
  $('.span3').toggle('slow');
});
```

```css
.small-span img {
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3" style="background-color: tomato">this is fluid</div>
    <div class="span1 small-span">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/25x25" />
    </div>
    <div class="span8" style="background-color: lightblue">yeah!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your example but doing this, the span8 is not taking the all width on the right. I want something that cover the three span in 100% width so in that case I need to use span9 and remove the margins?

Comment: How about the new approach? The span wrapped inside span4.

Comment: this is really good! I'm just playing with the size of the image placeholder when is maximized to keep always the same size but I can't find where to modify it

Comment: In fact I can't put the image placeholder inside the span4 because the final idea is to click on the image and hide the section on the left, and if I click again, the div with span4 should come back

Comment: Then you will need to go with the previous approach. Check the toggle function too.

Comment: I know you wanted the span to cover less space. But that is not how the grid system works, unfortunately. It will break the code when you make it more complex. I tried wrapping the code in earlier version but it would hide the image inside which is used to toggle as well. Hope you get it! :)